# enter positive and negative values based on a target date in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with stock data and would like enter negative and positive integers (depicting days) before and after a target_date - per below:

What I have (date is the index):

```
date      symbol    open    high    low close   volume
12/9/1988   AAPL    1.4018  1.4107  1.3839  1.3975  11239200
12/12/1988  AAPL    1.4018  1.4107  1.375   1.375   29470000
12/13/1988  AAPL    1.375   1.3839  1.3661  1.3839  30637600
12/14/1988  AAPL    1.375   1.4286  1.375   1.4196  48325200
12/15/1988  AAPL    1.4286  1.4464  1.4018  1.4107  28142800
12/16/1988  AAPL    1.4107  1.4464  1.4018  1.4332  45872400
12/19/1988  AAPL    1.4375  1.4643  1.4286  1.4554  58581600
12/20/1988  AAPL    1.4643  1.4821  1.4511  1.4643  68546800
12/21/1988  AAPL    1.4643  1.5 1.4643  1.4911  60491200
12/22/1988  AAPL    1.4911  1.5 1.4554  1.4643  26507600
12/23/1988  AAPL    1.4643  1.4779  1.4643  1.4689  10239600
12/27/1988  AAPL    1.4643  1.4821  1.4464  1.4464  14996800
12/28/1988  AAPL    1.4464  1.4554  1.4196  1.4375  12885600
```

Below is representation of what I would like where the target_date is 12/16/1988:

> 1. create a column called "day"
> 2. at the target date (e.g., 12/16/1988) - enter a '0' in the "day" column
> 3. in the "day" column - before the target date enter -1 to -n (length of the df before the date)
> 4. in the "day" column - after the target date enter 1 to n (length of the df after the date)

```
date       day  symbol  open    high    low close   volume
12/9/1988   -5  AAPL    1.4018  1.4107  1.3839  1.3975  11239200
12/12/1988  -4  AAPL    1.4018  1.4107  1.375   1.375   29470000
12/13/1988  -3  AAPL    1.375   1.3839  1.3661  1.3839  30637600
12/14/1988  -2  AAPL    1.375   1.4286  1.375   1.4196  48325200
12/15/1988  -1  AAPL    1.4286  1.4464  1.4018  1.4107  28142800
12/16/1988  0   AAPL    1.4107  1.4464  1.4018  1.4332  45872400
12/19/1988  1   AAPL    1.4375  1.4643  1.4286  1.4554  58581600
12/20/1988  2   AAPL    1.4643  1.4821  1.4511  1.4643  68546800
12/21/1988  3   AAPL    1.4643  1.5 1.4643  1.4911  60491200
12/22/1988  4   AAPL    1.4911  1.5 1.4554  1.4643  26507600
12/23/1988  5   AAPL    1.4643  1.4779  1.4643  1.4689  10239600
12/27/1988  6   AAPL    1.4643  1.4821  1.4464  1.4464  14996800
12/28/1988  7   AAPL    1.4464  1.4554  1.4196  1.4375  12885600
```

I have considered taking the following approach (found on SO, but can't locate the source):

```
lenDF = (int(len(df) / 2))
df.insert(0, 'day', range(-lenDF, -lenDF + len(df)))
```

This doesn't work exactly right for my purposes before the length of the df before the target date can be different than after the target date. It doesn't match '0' in the "day" column with the target_date.

I also tried truncating the df before and after the target date - but same problem as the above solution - it doesn't match '0' in the "day" column with the target_date.

```
df_before_target = df.truncate(before=target_date)
df_after_target = df.truncate(after=target_date)

len_b4 = len(df_before_target ) - 1  # substracting 1 to account for double counting of target_date in the truncated dfs.

len_a4 = len(df_after_target )
df.insert(0, 'day', range(-len_b4, -len_a4 + len(df)))
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I noticed you are skipping weekends in the `days` column calculation.  Are you skipping stat holidays too?

Comment: jeschwar - that is correct, I am ignoring weekends/holiday - that is, all non-market days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think numpy's `busday_count()` will work well here.

I prefer working in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation for the dates.  You can do this by using pandas' `DatetimeIndex` class:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

We can get the data for your desired column as follows:

```
days = [np.busday_count('1988-12-16', x.date()) for x in df.index]
```

which iterates over every `pd.Timestamp` object in your `DatetimeIndex` and calculates the difference (from a business day perspective) with your target date of `1988-12-16`.

Then you can assign this data to you dataframe as follows:

```
df['day'] = days
```

and reorder the columns as shown in your post:

```
df.reindex(columns=['day', 'symbol', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
```

Comment: Thanks, jeschwar - this works well, and it is simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possibly hacky solution but it should do the job.

```
df["day"] = df.index.values - df[df[date] == "TARGET DATE"].index[0]
```

Comment: It's implicit that someone with a question about your answer can ask a follow-up question. It is certainly friendly to include that explicitly, but it doesn't really add to your answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to helping people on SO ^^

Comment: Gatien C - thanks - I think this works as desired. Or at least it did on one data set. Trying to apply it on multiple data sets in a for loop, but running into index error issues: 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0' - I am trying to figure it what I am doing wrong here. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of calculating the days.

```
dataset=pd.DataFrame(test)
dataset.head()
```

output of your original data:

```
      date     symbol   high
0   12/9/1988   AAPL    1.4018
1   12/12/1988  AAPL    1.4018
2   12/13/1988  AAPL    1.3750
3   12/14/1988  AAPL    1.3750
4   12/15/1988  AAPL    1.4286

from datetime import datetime
dataset=pd.DataFrame(test)
dataset['date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset['date']) 
target_date = datetime.strptime('12/16/1988', "%m/%d/%Y")
dataset['Days']= (dataset['date'] - (target_date)).dt.days
dataset.head()
```

output:

```
       date    symbol    high   Days
0   1988-12-09  AAPL    1.4018  -7
1   1988-12-12  AAPL    1.4018  -4
2   1988-12-13  AAPL    1.3750  -3
3   1988-12-14  AAPL    1.3750  -2
4   1988-12-15  AAPL    1.4286  -1
```

Comment: Vishwas - this does work, but counts as number of days, not number of rows before or after target date. So it accounts for non-market days - weekends/holidays. This will be good back up if I can't get the desired solution to work. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code with changes and the output being reflected. If you are okay with the answer, I appreciate if you could upvote or accept the answer.